# How would I write a google cloud function to read firestore data and send a push notification to a user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to google's firebase framework and a novice programmer.  I have data in my firebase firestore, but need to write a google cloud function to access that data to determine when to send a push notification to a user.

To be more specific, I'm looking for a date saved in the firestore database to trigger a push notification to a user.

Right now I just have a index.js file and the below code.  Let me know what else I should show to get my question answered.

Thanks

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendItemEventNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userEmail}/items/{userItem}/dates/{itemDate}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const userItem = change.after.data().itemName;
        const userItemDate = change.after.data().ItemDateDate;

        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `Notification title`,
                body: `You just added a new item event for ${userItem} on ${userItemDate}`
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice("notifications", payload)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Successfully sent message")
                return;
            })
            .catch(data => {
                console.log("Error sending message")
                return;
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Cloud Function that listens to update events on a Firestore document, see here for the Node.js quickstart in writing a Cloud Function [1], note that the quickstart is for writing a Cloud Function triggered by HTTP requests and you will have to set the trigger to Cloud Firestore and set the event type to update, see here for more information on Cloud Firestore Triggers [2]. From what I understand, you are looking for a field (date) in a Firestore document. For illustrative purposes, let's say  we have a Cloud Function that looks like the following:

```js
/**
 * Triggered by a change to a Firestore document.
 *
 * @param {!Object} event Event payload.
 * @param {!Object} context Metadata for the event.
 */
exports.helloFirestore = (event, context) => {
  //If you have a document that has a "date" field, you can access it like such
  const date = event.value.fields.date // Will return {stringValue: "datedate"}
  const otherDate = event.value.fields.date.stringValue // Will return "datedate"
};
```

For further illustrative purposes, the event object looks like this (`console.log(JSON.stringify(event))`):

```
{  
   "oldValue":{  
      "createTime":"2019-08-14T02:46:50.108417Z",
      "fields":{  
         "date":{  
            "stringValue":"qqq"
         }
      },
      "name":"projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION>/<DOCUMENT>",
      "updateTime":"2019-08-14T03:03:59.568639Z"
   },
   "updateMask":{  
      "fieldPaths":[  
         "date"
      ]
   },
   "value":{  
      "createTime":"2019-08-14T02:46:50.108417Z",
      "fields":{  
         "date":{  
            "stringValue":"this had been changed"
         }
      },
      "name":"projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/databases/(default)/documents/<COLLECTION>/<DOCUMENT>",
      "updateTime":"2019-08-14T03:03:59.568639Z"
   }
}
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs

[2] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#code_sample

Comment: Thanks for the response, it helped me get on the right path.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I had a follow up question and I'm not sure if it is worth creating a new post. You did answer my original question, but I should have written "cloud functions for firebase" instead of "google cloud function." As of now I have the updated code in my original post. I'd like to know how to send a push notification to a device, currently it only logs a successful message sent without a notification on the android device.  Thanks for the help.